# How to give process name for a java application in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am running two `java` application in `ubuntu`,I googled for this,but i am not getting how to give the unique process name to each java application.I am running the applications as a jar files (`java -jar app.jar`).But when i see the process using shell command top .

It is showing only java,not applications name.Any help regarding this.

Comment: did you try with `htop`, there is an option to 'Highlight program "basename"'

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ps -aef | grep java` from your terminal.
It will list running Java commands, from which you can deduce application names by looking at the command parameters.

Comment: I want to bring the java application to front of the user by using process name like (wmctrl -a "Mozilla Firefox"),but for java application wmctrl is not working.Can we get the java application to front by using process id instead of process name

Answer (score 0):

If this is to start / stop a Java process, you can do a startup script like that :

```
#!/bin/sh

PROGRAM_NAME=sicm
PROGRAM_HOME=/usr/local/sicm
PIDFILE=/var/run/$PROGRAM_NAME.pid

application_start() {
        CMDLINE="/usr/lib/java/bin/java -jar $PROGRAM_NAME.jar"
        echo -n "Starting $PROGRAM_NAME daemon: $CMDLINE"
        cd $PROGRAM_HOME

        /usr/lib/java/bin/java -classpath lib -jar $PROGRAM_NAME.jar &
        ps -Ao pid,command | grep java | grep $PROGRAM_NAME.jar | awk '{print $1}' > $PIDFILE
        echo
}

application_stop() {
        echo -n "Stopping $PROGRAM_NAME daemon..."

        if [ -r $PIDFILE ]; then
                PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
                if [ $PID -gt 0 ]; then
                        kill $PID
                        echo
                        sleep 1
                        fi
                rm -f $PIDFILE
        fi
        killall $PROGRAM_NAME
}

application_restart() {
        application_stop
        sleep 1
        application_start
}

case "$1" in
'start')
        application_start
        ;;
'stop')
        application_stop
        ;;
'restart')
        application_restart
        ;;
*)
        echo "usage $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
```

Comment: I want to bring the java application to front of the user by using process name like (wmctrl -a "Mozilla Firefox"),but for java application wmctrl is not working.Can we get the java application to front by using process id instead of process name.

Comment: I really don't know, here is the documentation http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl but looks like they only can show list of PID of windows...

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

If you run your command in the background (add `&` at the end), you can get the PID of using [`$!`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIDVARREF) :

> PID (process ID) of last job run in background

#### Command

```
java -jar app.jar &; echo $!
```

Comment: I want to bring the java application to front of the user by using process name like (wmctrl -a "Mozilla Firefox"),but for java application wmctrl is not working.Can we get the java application to front by using process id instead of process name

Comment: That's something different from what you originally asked. Try a new question